# Remove (Postfix) pattern in postfix email header

Tags: postfix, smtp-headers

Due security due diligent, we need to remove the pattern (Postfix) in our email header.

Here is an eg:

```
Received: from Simon-Vs-MBCuiPap.local (unknown [118.69.224.5])
    (using TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    (Authenticated sender: thang.vc@domain.com)
    by mail.domain.com ***(Postfix)*** with ESMTPSA id DE1545E37B
    for <simon.unix@yahoo.com>; Wed, 16 May 2012 15:38:47 +0800 (SGT)
```

How can i remove (Postfix) and keep other information ?
I try to use header_check by REPLACE, but it is replacing whole line, not only for (Postfix)

Pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

You remove email headers at your own peril; I cannot believe any company would be stupid enough to think that standards compliance to promote interoperability will have negative security impacts of any magnitude.

Comment: Hi,<p> i got the solutions now by edit main.cf file and put <p> mail_name="whatever"